# onClick() method for a ListView

Tags: android, listview, onclicklistener, toast

Today I was working on my application in Android Studio, which loads in different movie titles from a API including a picture, and a name.

Now I got that working but I'm struggling with the onClick() function of the ListView.
I want to be able to click on certain movie titles and be able to see 3 options, read more, rate and comment.

But that is not the point, I can't get the onClick() function to work for the ListView.
As it is right now, I'm trying to view a toast, just to test if it works, but for some reason it won't.
The app boots up fine, no errors, and noting happens when I click on the titles.   So I've got nothing to troubleshoot with.
If you guys could help me, that would be awesome!

```
    lv= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
    adapter=new CustomAdapter(this, TVShowsCollection.getTVShows());
```

This is the first part

```
            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position,
                                long arg3)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //String value = (String)adapter.getItemAtPosition(position);
        }
    });
```

Second part, with the xml

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.example.wrapped.wrapped.MainActivity"

tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: just put a Log.d("TAG","Item clicked at"+position); inside your onItemClick and check if there is any log

Answer (score 2):

The second argument of a `Toast` is a `CharSequence`, so you try to display a int value, you have to replace `position` by `String.valueOf(position)` :

> ```
> static Toast  makeText(Context context, CharSequence text, intduration)
> ```
>
> Make a standard toast that just contains a text view.

**Note** that Toast can take an integer value in the second arguments, however this integer is a resource id :

> `static Toast    makeText(Context context, int resId, int duration)`
>
> Make a standard toast that just contains a text view with the text
>   from a resource.

Comment: Using `String.valurOf(position)` instead of `position+""` is more efficient.

Comment: @MarcEstrada agree

Comment: Great, but you typed `valurOf` :) can't edit your answer only for 1 char

Comment: Oh, copy past from you comment :D

Comment: Lol, so sorry :)

Comment: Well, I've tried to put a simple ''hello!'' toast, wich I've implemented in my login page aswell, it works perfectly over there but no response from my listview. thanks for the responses! So I'm not sure if it's reading my click at all, i log stuff aswell on mouseclick, but that logs something when someone clicks the list in general, not a specific item, but I'll give it a go!

Comment: Is your OnItemClickListener  a android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() ??

Comment: Can you edit you question by adding your listview declaration (xml)?

Comment: Added the xml, yet nothing special there, I did however managed to get this message in my run terminal when I click the elements "D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN" Don't know what to make of it though. I'm sorry for being vague, I'm a beginner with android, again, thanks for the help!